# Updating DIV with XML content on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

The concept of what I'm trying to do is fairly simple.  I have a grid of company logos loaded through XSLT from an XML document, each with their own unique links to the company profiles.

I have a separate div on the page, essentially a "preview" box.  What I want to do is this:

I roll over a logo, and it loads the name of the company and a short description into the preview div.  This content is loaded through XML.

I have been messing around with the Jquery load() function, changing the target document to load on Hover—and it almost gets what I want, but it loads the whole target XML document into the div.

How can I separate this target XML data into separate divs? (which I have styled differently)
I'd assume I would make use of Ajax in some way.  I want to load the `<name>` node into the name_div, and the `<desc>` node into the description_div, and have them update on hover.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Here are some examples of the code I'm working with:

portfolio.xml file (this file is my main page, displaying the grid and preview div, example uses 3 companies):

```
<portfolio>
    <company>
        <name>ABC Company</name>
        <sdesc>Consumer products</sdesc>
        <logo-thumb>abcco.jpg</logo-thumb>
        <link>abcco.xml</link>
    </company>

    <company>
        <name>DEF Company</name>
        <sdesc>Communications firm</sdesc>
        <logo-thumb>defco.jpg</logo-thumb>
        <link>defco.xml</link>
    </company>
    <company>
        <name>GHI Corporation</name>
        <sdesc>Electronic products</sdesc>
        <logo-thumb>ghico.jpg</logo-thumb>
        <link>ghico.xml</link>
    </company>
</portfolio>
```

The following XSLT displays that code on the page:

```
<xsl:for-each select="portfolio/company">
     <xsl:sort select="name" />

       <div class="invest-port-thumb">
         <a>
         <xsl:attribute name="href">
              <xsl:value-of select="link" />
         </xsl:attribute>

         <img>
         <xsl:attribute name="src">
              <xsl:value-of select="logo-thumb" />
         </xsl:attribute>
         </img>
         </a>
       </div>

</xsl:for-each>
```

This is the HTML structure of the "preview div":

```
<div id="preview">

<div id="preview-name"> [Name to display here] </div>
<div id="preview-desc"> [Description to display here] </div>

</div>
```

All 3 company logos are loaded into the page, each displaying a linked image loaded from . Desired effect is to on hover, display the contents of  in the "preview-name" div, and the contents of  in the "preview-desc" div.

---

Let me try to be a bit more specific. Here are some examples:

portfolio.xml file (this file is my main page, displaying the grid and preview div, example uses 3 companies):

```
<portfolio>
    <company>
        <name>ABC Company</name>
        <sdesc>Consumer products</sdesc>
        <logo-thumb>abcco.jpg</logo-thumb>
        <link>abcco.xml</link>
    </company>

    <company>
        <name>DEF Company</name>
        <sdesc>Communications firm</sdesc>
        <logo-thumb>defco.jpg</logo-thumb>
        <link>defco.xml</link>
    </company>
    <company>
        <name>GHI Corporation</name>
        <sdesc>Electronic products</sdesc>
        <logo-thumb>ghico.jpg</logo-thumb>
        <link>ghico.xml</link>
    </company>
</portfolio>
```

The following XSLT displays that code on the page:

```
<xsl:for-each select="portfolio/company">
     <xsl:sort select="name" />

       <div class="invest-port-thumb">
         <a>
         <xsl:attribute name="href">
              <xsl:value-of select="link" />
         </xsl:attribute>

         <img>
         <xsl:attribute name="src">
              <xsl:value-of select="logo-thumb" />
         </xsl:attribute>
         </img>
         </a>
       </div>

</xsl:for-each>
```

This is the HTML structure of the "preview div":

```
<div id="preview">

<div id="preview-name"> [Name to display here] </div>
<div id="preview-desc"> [Description to display here] </div>

</div>
```

All 3 company logos are loaded into the page, each displaying a linked image loaded from `<logo-thumb>`.  Desired effect is to on hover, display the contents of `<name>` in the "preview-name" div, and the contents of `<sdesc>` in the "preview-desc" div.

Comment: I'm interested (academically) in finding out if/how XSL works out when loading XML via XMLHttpRequest

Comment: You haven't considered loading the entire document into jquery via ajax, parsing the XML and then appending the necessary info to each element? Will elaborate if you want..

Comment: That's another option. I just figured that would be harder to do.  Currently, I have my page set up like that I think.  I have all of the companies in the XML file, each with their name and description.  I'm just not sure how to separate that out and display the content based on which image I've hovered over.

Comment: @Andrew: in order to provide a complete answer we need input and output example. If all the data for links and preview are in one XML document you could run this in one XSLT stylesheet (apply styles with CSS later, of corse)

Comment: As far as how you're doing it, I would be strongly inclined to do the xml processing server-side in this instance, then you can do the UI/HTML/CSS/JavaScript a bit more cleanly.

StackOverflow issue: If you need to update your question use the "edit" feature, don't do it as a new answer.

Comment: Good to know. I'm new to all of this...so you're saying maybe use something like PHP for this type of application?

Comment: @Andrew Parisi - for **me** that's how I'd handle it, use PHP (or other available server-side language) to parse the xml and generate your html. Then it's a matter of that html to call JS and CSS to get you the effects you want. Part of the issue is there are MANY ways to handle this. I like server-parsing because it's the most compatible way to do it (stick client-side to html+css+js). It's a judgment call and your way is perfectly legit too.

Comment: So does anyone have an idea of where I could start by doing this in a client-side fashion?  I don't want to try to delve into PHP if I can do this in the format I'm already working in (Jquery/JS) and such. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my question to add in my extra information..sorry about the double answer.  won't be doing that again..

Comment: @ Andrew Parisi: I'd suggest you split the javascript code into data handling and display handling. That means, get a javascript code that performs the XHR request to your XML, then get another function to parse the document and apply the requested data.

Answer (score 1):

Preserving the semantics of your page and the structure of your stylesheet, I try to do something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="portfolio/company"> 
     <xsl:sort select="name" /> 
     <div class="invest-port-thumb"> 
       <a href="{link}"><img src="{logo-thumb}" /></a>
       <div class="preview"> 
         <div class="preview-name"><xsl:value-of select="name" /></div> 
         <div class="preview-desc"><xsl:value-of select="sdesc" /></div> 
       </div> 
     </div> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Then, in CSS stylesheet, you can use `:hover` pseudoclass and `+` combinator to show or hide preview. There ara some problems with crossbrowser compatibility. You should check [Stu Nicholls site](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/) for better semantics and CSS examples.

Comment: The preview box will always be visible, and contain the information of the last company rolled over until you roll over a new one...The problem with using value-of, is that it will only pull the first <name> node out of my XML file, instead of the one I hover on.

Comment: @Andrew: You want to make asynchronous something that it's synchronous! You have all the data in XML document. Then transform that whith XSLT. At last, apply style with CSS (add a link element in your transformation, of course). The complexity is not in XSLT (The one I'd posted worked just fine. If you'll post your complete stylesheet we could help you more). The complexity is in cross-browser CSS for your layout. Check the Nicholls' site for example. For living example of what I'm talking about check one of my sites: http://www.aranedabienesraices.com.ar

Comment: I agree with Alejandro. You need to get the HTML loaded like you want from the XSLT. Then you can hide all the DIVs other than the one being previewed. 

You could also give each preview-data DIV an ID and then load the preview DIV with the preview-data based on that ID. The ID could correspond to whatever the user's are hovering on.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you `load()` can take a selector after the url and only return a part of the ajax call.

So, something like:

```
$('#name_div').load('/path/yourXmlFile.xml name:first');
```

Now, making network calls every time you want to look at something is not very efficient. You probably want to cache the output into a variable.

Comment: Good point. I'm not limited to that method of display--it's just something I've experimented with.  Currently, the source of the file displaying the whole grid already HAS all of the data I need to display in XML.  Any insight on how I could display that already loaded data into the div based on which image I've rolled over?

Comment: You need to create an association between what's in the xml and your divs. Perhaos into the images rolled over you would add an id like `id="image-55"` then in your xml you have a structure that also embeds the id, like `<container id="image-55">...</container>`

Answer (score 0):

I would feed the name and desc into the anchor as part of the anchor or it's child image, perhaps using the ALT tag for the name and REL tag for the description.

On hover over any anchor, I'll use jQuery [.attr()] to grab the attribute values containing the name and description you want and spit that into your respective target DIVs.

(See 'Recipe Categories' in http://www.masterchef.com.au/home.htm for similar example)