# Change multiple div contents on another div mouse hover without css/with an xml source file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I'm working on [this site](http://animevid-list.webflow.io/), and I need to change the contents of `image_preview`, `title_preview`, `description_preview`, `link_preview` according to what I'm hovering over (ex: `mouse hover "button_a" = image1.png, iliketitle, ulikedesc, welikelink`).

I've tried using css solutions like [this](http://goo.gl/u9dLUV) and [this](http://goo.gl/hPHlHc), but I wasn't able to make them work like I needed.

Since the page will have many `button_#`'s (50-100 buttons), I think css isn't a proper choice.
So what I'm looking for is a way to do this **without css**, better if with an **xml source file**, so it'd be easier to manage the content to display for each button. I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038424/updating-div-with-xml-content-on-hover) talking about the xml I'd need, but I'm not sure that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons have a class (e.g. `.btn`) and the associated data to each button is store somewhere, let's say each button has a `data-*` attribute which points to the right data.

```
$('.btn').hover(function() {
    var data = $(this).data('something');
    if(data == "b1") {
        //assign the values related to b1
    }
    else if(data == "b2") {
        //assign the values related to b2
    }
    //and so on
}
```

If you have a lot of buttons like that, then the data can be a reference to an array containing the proper info.

Here's a [**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/Lsdg80y1/).

And here's [**updated DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/Lsdg80y1/1/).

**EDIT:**

`.hover()` can take two handler which the second will handle when mouse is out of the element.

```
yourElement.hover(
    function() {
        //mouse is on the element, do stuff
    },
    function() {
        //mouse is out, do other stuff
    }
);
```

You can have a function to set the default values and call that in hover's second function.

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/Lsdg80y1/2/)

Comment: Looks fine, does it work same way for images and links ?

Comment: Yes, see the updated demo. If you mean hovering over images or links instead of button, then you won't need any change, just bind the hover to the element you want.

Comment: I forgot to ask a thing, is it possible to restore the original contents while not hovering any buttons ?

Comment: Me again, what if i'd like to trigger the event on mouse click instead on hover, or just want both event? I mean, while being over the buttons show all the stuff changing, but when a button is clicked also if no more over the button it keep showing his related changes ? Hope you got what i mean, thanks again.

Comment: You can use `click()` instead of `hover()`, just note that it only takes one handler. The other part I don't understand. If you mean if a button clicked then hovers shouldn't work, then you can use `$(this).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave')` inside your click function, so the hovers won't work afterwards.

Comment: that was exactly what i meant, nice job!